# How to properly handle Private Route in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, next.js

I am trying to learn some Next.js and I've been stuck for about 2 days thinking and looking for the answer to my question. 
I have a simple MERN app where auth user can add a post to his blog and remove it etc. 
 
My auth is working that way: In my Express backend after successful user login, the cookie is set up with a JWT token. To check whether the token is valid or not I have another route where the user can make a request and it takes that token and verifies if. I use this for my PrivateRoute component that handles access to specific components. It works fine but after I make a request to log in the user and redirect him to the default page when I open the console I can see that cookie in my front end (localhost:3000) but when I open the console in my backend (localhost:5000) there is no cookie. It only appears after I refresh the page. 
 
I asked some guys on discord and they told me to rewrite my react to next.js and it would be much better. 
 So I thought that it could be fun so I started by learning that. I found some tutorials on private routes but none of them really help me. 
 
Is there a better way to handle this than making a request in getServerSideProps and then display or redirect the component based on the response?

Also, could I make it somehow to make that request initially when the app is loading and then have some kind of user context to store that response?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `It works fine but after I make request to login user and redirect him to default page when I open console I can see that cookie in my front end (localhost:3000) but when I open console in my backend (localhost:5000) there is no cookie. It only appears after I refresh page` After you redirect, how to set the cookie in your frontend before request to make it appear in your backend console? And what things happen when you refresh the page

Comment: I handle setting cookie in my backend code and I do not know why but after login I can see this cookie in my frontend instantly but to see this in my backend I need to refresh page or login twice.